# syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to mongoose but when I require the mongoose package at the top it throws me an error
"Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token".It doesn't change even if I commented on my models.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const feedRoutes = require("./routes/feed");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(feedRoutes);

mongoose
.connect(
 "mongodb+srv://name:password@reactrest-dkohi.mongodb.net/barber",
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
)
.then(result => {
 app.listen(8080);
 console.log("connected");
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

my model post.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema(
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
},
{
  timestamps: true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

And this is the Error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\document-disk(d)\SIDEPROJECT\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\index.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post a more detailed error message. Where exactly does it point to with its syntax error?

Comment: You do not require body parser if you are using `express.js` just suggestion.
Instead you can use ```app.use(express.json())```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, requiring the mongoose package like this;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

I am using node.js version 12.22.9

Requiring the mongoose package displayed the following error

> ```
> C:\Users\hp\Desktop\web\v8node\cleanbloglate\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\add_user.js:16
>     this.options = options ?? {};
>                             ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\web\v8node\cleanbloglate\node_modules\mongodb\lib\admin.js:4:20)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

I first tried to uninstall mongoose then install it again and discovered it was displaying some errors I had earlier ignored resulting from the installation as below;

> C:\Users\hp\Desktop\web\v8node\cleanbloglate>npm install mongoose npm
> WARN notsup Unsupported engine for mongoose@7.3.1: wanted:
> {"node":">=14.20.1"} (current: {"node":"12.22.9","npm":"6.14.15"}) npm
> WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm:
> mongoose@7.3.1 npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for bson@5.3.0:
> wanted: {"node":">=14.20.1"} (current:
> {"node":"12.22.9","npm":"6.14.15"}) npm WARN notsup Not compatible
> with your version of node/npm: bson@5.3.0 npm WARN notsup Unsupported
> engine for mquery@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=14.0.0"} (current:
> {"node":"12.22.9","npm":"6.14.15"}) npm WARN notsup Not compatible
> with your version of node/npm: mquery@5.0.0 npm WARN notsup
> Unsupported engine for mongodb@5.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=14.20.1"}
> (current: {"node":"12.22.9","npm":"6.14.15"}) npm WARN notsup Not
> compatible with your version of node/npm: mongodb@5.6.0 npm WARN
> bootstrap@5.2.3 requires a peer of @popperjs/core@^2.11.6 but none is
> installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2
> (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

So I then uninstalled mongoose version 7.3.1 again and manually installed mongoose version 6.0.0

These are the only errors i got upon installing mongoose 6.0.0 on my local machine that has node.js version 12.22.9

> C:\Users\hp\Desktop\web\v8node\cleanbloglate>npm install
> mongoose@6.0.0 npm WARN bootstrap@5.2.3 requires a peer of
> @popperjs/core@^2.11.6 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

No serious errors and suddenly my application started working

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a misplaced bracket in postSchema, between email and timestamps. Does below snippet work?

```
const postSchema = new Schema(
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  {
  timestamps: true
  }
});
```

Comment: even if I commented on this model the error still occurs. It seems the problem is connecting to the mongoose. In app.js if I commented on the  `const mongoose = require("mongoose");`  and write app.listen(8080)  it does work fine.